pipeline with only simple $lookup stage automatically unwinds the data in the root place without using $unwind in pymongo python, is it possible?
I have two collections "users" and "persons", the "users" collection has an ObjectId of the "persons" collection ("person_id: "ObjectId("some_string")", I'm trying to get all users with the related data from the "persons" collection.
Although I used a simple $lookup, unfortunately, I got an inappropriate result

My pipeline is:

pipeline = [
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "persons",
            "localField": "person_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "person_lookup_data"
        }
    }
]


My users collection is:

[
    {
        "_id": { "$oid": "66447289442c0747d99f53d2" },
        "person_id": { "$oid": "66447288442c0747d99f53d1" },
        "role": "regular_r",
        "created_at": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1715761801362" } },
        "updated_at": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1715761801362" } }
    },
    {
        "_id": { "$oid": "66450e6a2ece17f018ddbe65" },
        "person_id": { "$oid": "66450e692ece17f018ddbe64" },
        "role": "regular_r",
        "created_at": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1715801706337" } },
        "updated_at": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1715801706337" } }
    }
]


My persons collection is:

[
    {
        "_id": { "$oid": "66447288442c0747d99f53d1" },
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "a@b.com",
        "password": "123456",
        "phone_number": "0529248906",
        "alternative_number": "0987654321",
        "address": { "$oid": "66447287442c0747d99f53d0" },
        "gender": "Male",
        "birthday": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "376444800000" } },
        "profile_image": "some image",
        "profile_icon": "some icon",
        "active": true,
        "added_by": "normal",
        "created_at": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1715761800275" } },
        "updated_at": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1715761800275" } }
    },
    {
        "_id": { "$oid": "66450e692ece17f018ddbe64" },
        "first_name": "Dana",
        "last_name": "Levi",
        "email": "dana@levi.com",
        "password": "123456",
        "phone_number": "0529248906",
        "alternative_number": "0987654321",
        "address": { "$oid": "66450e672ece17f018ddbe63" },
        "gender": "Female",
        "birthday": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "379296000000" } },
        "profile_image": "some image",
        "profile_icon": "some icon",
        "active": true,
        "added_by": "normal",
        "created_at": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1715801705281" } },
        "updated_at": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1715801705281" } }
    }
]


my aggregate function is:

    def aggregate(self, pipeline):
        # Execute aggregation query
        result = list(self.__db['users'].aggregate(pipeline))
        print("result = ", result)
        return result


But unfortunately, this is the result:

    [
        {
            "_id": "66447288442c0747d99f53d1",
            "active": true,
            "added_by": "normal",
            "address": "66447287442c0747d99f53d0",
            "alternative_number": "0987654321",
            "birthday": "1981-12-06T00:00:00",
            "created_at": "2024-05-15T08:30:00.275000",
            "email": "a@b.com",
            "first_name": "John",
            "gender": "Male",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "password": "123456",
            "person_lookup_data": [],
            "phone_number": "0529248906",
            "profile_icon": "some icon",
            "profile_image": "some image",
            "updated_at": "2024-05-15T08:30:00.275000"
        },
        {
            "_id": "66450e692ece17f018ddbe64",
            "active": true,
            "added_by": "normal",
            "address": "66450e672ece17f018ddbe63",
            "alternative_number": "0987654321",
            "birthday": "1982-01-08T00:00:00",
            "created_at": "2024-05-15T19:35:05.281000",
            "email": "dana@levi.com",
            "first_name": "Dana",
            "gender": "Female",
            "last_name": "Levi",
            "password": "123456",
            "person_lookup_data": [],
            "phone_number": "0529248906",
            "profile_icon": "some icon",
            "profile_image": "some image",
            "updated_at": "2024-05-15T19:35:05.281000"
        }
    ]


This is the expected result:

    [
        {
            "_id": "66447289442c0747d99f53d2",
            "created_at": "2024-05-15T08:30:01.362000",
            "person_id": "66447288442c0747d99f53d1",
            "person_lookup_data": [
                {
                    "_id": "66447288442c0747d99f53d1",
                    "active": true,
                    "added_by": "normal",
                    "address": "66447287442c0747d99f53d0",
                    "alternative_number": "0987654321",
                    "birthday": "1981-12-06T00:00:00",
                    "created_at": "2024-05-15T08:30:00.275000",
                    "email": "a@b.com",
                    "first_name": "John",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "last_name": "Doe",
                    "password": "123456",
                    "phone_number": "0529248906",
                    "profile_icon": "some icon",
                    "profile_image": "some image",
                    "updated_at": "2024-05-15T08:30:00.275000"
                }
            ],
            "role": "regular_r",
            "updated_at": "2024-05-15T08:30:01.362000"
        },
        {
            "_id": "66450e6a2ece17f018ddbe65",
            "created_at": "2024-05-15T19:35:06.337000",
            "person_id": "66450e692ece17f018ddbe64",
            "person_lookup_data": [
                {
                    "_id": "66450e692ece17f018ddbe64",
                    "active": true,
                    "added_by": "normal",
                    "address": "66450e672ece17f018ddbe63",
                    "alternative_number": "0987654321",
                    "birthday": "1982-01-08T00:00:00",
                    "created_at": "2024-05-15T19:35:05.281000",
                    "email": "dana@levi.com",
                    "first_name": "Dana",
                    "gender": "Female",
                    "last_name": "Levi",
                    "password": "123456",
                    "phone_number": "0529248906",
                    "profile_icon": "some icon",
                    "profile_image": "some image",
                    "updated_at": "2024-05-15T19:35:05.281000"
                }
            ],
            "role": "regular_r",
            "updated_at": "2024-05-15T19:35:06.337000"
        }
    ]

Please can someone help me?

If you print(pipeline) right before you use it, what does it show?

However, if I add into the URL any ID as a params without using a match into the pipeline query, I receive the expected result. it's very strange, someone can explain?
'''http://localhost:5000/users/66447287442c0747d99f53d0'''

problem solved!
The problem occurred because in the business logic layer file I mistakenly used person_model instead of user_model:
Wrong use:
users = self.__person_model.aggregate(pipeline)
result = list(self.__db['persons'].aggregate(pipeline))

Correct usage:
users = self.__user_model.aggregate(pipeline)
result = list(self.__db['users'].aggregate(pipeline))

